# How to select files from a specific extension

Tags: applescript-objc

I would like to know how to select only a certain extension using file choose in AppleScript.

`choose file of type {"png"} with multiple selections allowed`

I've tried something like this but my files with the PNG extension can not be selected, and I want whatever else is done.

Answer (score 0):

i solved, it was just put the name of the extension in the upper case.

`choose file of type {"PNG"} with multiple selections allowed`

Comment: You can also use a Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) such as "public.png".